# Single page alignment for IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css-float

I am designing master page for one good website. I have used firebug to design the appropriate css, but problem is when I open the page in IE. Alignment differs much.

Problem is with width, margin that I have placed for div blocks.

The whole page is here below.

```
<html>
<head>
<link src="Styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body{ 
    height:100%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    color:#403e3e,
    color:gray;font-size: 12pt;
}
#sections{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    float:left;
}
#container{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;   
    float: left;
}
.sectionBlock{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    border:0px dotted red;
    padding: 10px;
}
h3{ 
    color:#990033;
    font-family:Maiandra GD;
    margin:9px;
}
#info{
    float:left;
}
.secHead{ 
    font-size:20pt;
    font-family:Maiandra GD;
    color:#990033;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.secDescription{ font-size:10pt;}
a{ color:#990033;}
#navigation ul{ 
    background-image: url("img/bar.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    height:32px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
#navigation ul li{display:inline;padding:20px; font-size:16px;color:#302e2e;}
#footer {background-color:#E01B6A;}
#footer .footerText{margin:auto;width:100%;width: 340px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="navigation">

      <ul>
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>Application Tracker</li>    
         <li>Insurance Policy downloads</li>     
         <li>Parner Login</li>   
         <li>SiteMap</li>    
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="intro">
        <h3>How can we help you? </h3>
        Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
        omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet. 
         <a href="#moreInfo">Find out more</a>
        </div>

        <div id="sections">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <div class="sectionBlock">
              <div class="secHead"> Tenants
              </div>
              <div class="secDescription">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteur adipiscing elt, sed do elusmod tempor.<br/>
             <a href="#Tenants">Find out more</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sectionBlock">
              <div class="secHead">Landlords
              </div>
              <div class="secDescription">
              Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa elt, sed do elus mod tempor qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
              <a href="#Landlords">Find out more</a>
              </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="sectionBlock">
              <div class="secHead">Letting Agents
              </div>
              <div class="secDescription">
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa elt, sed do elus mod tempor qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
                <a href="#Letting Agents">Find out more</a>
              </div>            
            </div>      

        </div>
        <div id="info">
        Maras is an independent company specialising in supplying services to the residential lettings industry. If you are an applicant,
            letting agent or landlord Maras is here to help you. Maras Group is directly authorised and regulated by the Financial Services
            Authority for general insurance activities.
        <ul>
            <li>Providers of services to the letting industry for more than 15 years. </li>
            <li>Over 250,000 references processed per annum. </li>
            <li>Over 1.5 Million telephone calls processed per annum. </li>
            <li>One of the largest providers of services to the lettings industry. </li>
            <li>Real value for money products and services. </li>
        </ul>   
       </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"> <div class="footerText">Copyright 2008@, maras. All Rights Reserved.</div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone suggest style changes so that it should look same view in all browsers ?

Comment: @Maras, Thanks. Please use IE-8/9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a wrapper around the content of your page and set the 'text-align: center' to the body (which helps with centering elements in IE).

See the code below and tell me whether it works for you

```
<html>
<head>
<link src="Styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body{ height:100%; font-family: Tahoma; color:#403e3e, color:gray;font-size: 12pt; text-align: center;}
#wrapper { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
#sections{ width:100%; background-color:#EFEFEF; float:left; }
#container{background-color:#FFFFFF; float: left;}
.sectionBlock{ float:left; width:30%; border:0px dotted red; padding: 10px; }
h3{  color:#990033; font-family:Maiandra GD; margin:9px; }
#info{ float:left; }
.secHead{  font-size:20pt; font-family:Maiandra GD; color:#990033; margin-bottom:2px; }
.secDescription{ font-size:10pt;}
a{ color:#990033;}
#navigation ul{  background-image: url("img/bar.jpg"); margin: 0; height:32px; padding-top: 8px; padding-left:40px;}
#navigation ul li{display:inline;padding:20px; font-size:16px;color:#302e2e;}
#footer {background-color:#E01B6A; text-align: center;}
#footer .footerText{margin:auto;width:100%;width: 340px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
          <ul>
             <li>Home</li>
             <li>Application Tracker</li>    
             <li>Insurance Policy downloads</li>     
             <li>Parner Login</li>   
             <li>SiteMap</li>    
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="intro">
            <h3>How can we help you? </h3>
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
            omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet. 
             <a href="#moreInfo">Find out more</a>
            </div>

            <div id="sections">
              <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <div class="sectionBlock">
                  <div class="secHead"> Tenants
                  </div>
                  <div class="secDescription">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteur adipiscing elt, sed do elusmod tempor.<br/>
                 <a href="#Tenants">Find out more</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sectionBlock">
                  <div class="secHead">Landlords
                  </div>
                  <div class="secDescription">
                  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa elt, sed do elus mod tempor qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
                  <a href="#Landlords">Find out more</a>
                  </div>            
                </div>
                <div class="sectionBlock">
                  <div class="secHead">Letting Agents
                  </div>
                  <div class="secDescription">
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa elt, sed do elus mod tempor qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
                    <a href="#Letting Agents">Find out more</a>
                  </div>            
                </div>      

            </div>
            <div id="info">
            Maras is an independent company specialising in supplying services to the residential lettings industry. If you are an applicant,
                letting agent or landlord Maras is here to help you. Maras Group is directly authorised and regulated by the Financial Services
                Authority for general insurance activities.
            <ul>
                <li>Providers of services to the letting industry for more than 15 years. </li>
                <li>Over 250,000 references processed per annum. </li>
                <li>Over 1.5 Million telephone calls processed per annum. </li>
                <li>One of the largest providers of services to the lettings industry. </li>
                <li>Real value for money products and services. </li>
            </ul>   
           </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer"> <div class="footerText">Copyright 2008@, maras. All Rights Reserved.</div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1. Its amazing...! It would have been better to understand all readers with wrapper magic in couple of lines :)